# How can I get half the value of max-content width?

Tags: css, less

I'm showing a tooltip and I want it to be centered in the parent, no matter how long it is.

I was thinking that maybe I could use `calc()` with `max-content` but apparently that is not how it works.

```
*[tooltip] {
    position: relative;
    &:hover {
        &:after {
            content: attr(tooltip);
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: white;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0px;
            width: max-content;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:0.9em;
            text-align:center;
            margin-left: calc(max-content / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I can always use 100% as width but then it'll always be the width of the parent, and that is sometimes too little and other times it is too much; hence I use `max-content`.

```
<div tooltip="Hello World">Hover me.</div>
```

How can I solve this dilemma **without using JS**?

EDIT:

Here's an image of how it should look.

[image]

No matter how much text is in the tooltip, it should always be centered in the middle. If I use the 100% width approach it will stay in the middle but will always be of the same width, causing the words to break down onto new rows.

By using max-content the width is always different to the other tooltips, which is why it becomes hard for me to center it.

Comment: Can you provide some html structur or a picture of how it should look. The description is not very clear-

Comment: Edited the question @DomenikReitzner

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks @Paulie_D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `transform`

```
  *[tooltip] {
        position: relative;
        &:hover {
            &:after {
                content: attr(tooltip);
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                color: white;
                padding: 6px 12px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                /* this */
                left:50%; 
                transform:translateX(-50%);

                width: max-content;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:0.9em;
                text-align:center;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure it does...https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vaqRqv It centers based the width of the parent...

Comment: `display: inline-block;` was missing from your original answer :)

Comment: It's not required....the **essential** part of the centering is the `left:50%` and the `transform`

Comment: Check the pen I posted. Then check the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}

*[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

*[tooltip]:hover:after {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left:50%; 
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div tooltip="Hello World" class="parent">Hover me.</div>
```